# Unity - Canvas Size changes from one computer to the other

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am porting a video game from Xamarin to Unity.

The game uses, amonst other thing, Unity UI functionnalities (hence a canvas).

I did some work on one computer, adapting/placing the UI element I needed to the canvas, then saved and checked in my work into subversion.

I then checked-out the code from another machine and reopened the project, only to find out that the canvas size (and hence all the UI elements layout) was quite different and all over the place !

Why is that ? Did I omit to check-in some important file (for exemple metadata) into the source control ?

Thanks,

Régis

Answer (score 3):

This is because the canvas height and width is dependent on the resolution of the main monitor of the machine running the game/editor.

You'll want to look into using anchors and layout components to make the canvas responsive.

Unity is a how to article on building a responsive UI: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

Comment: Merci Jordan I shall look into this article ! Is there anyway of defining and locking the canvas for  a certain resolution ?

Comment: The Canvas Scaler mentioned in the article should help you.